# Determine which of the vectors are in span$[S]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S=\{(1,2,1),(1,1,-1),(4,5,-2)\}$.Which of the following vectors are in$[S]$?

1.$(0,0,0)$

2.$(1,1,0)$

3.$(2,-1,-8)$

4.$(-\frac 1 3,-\frac 1 3,\frac 1 3)$

5.$(1,0,1)$

6.$(1,-3,5)$

So this was the question in my textbook and I tried to solve it according to Gauss-elimination method.
Suppose for the first option i.e $(0,0,0)$

let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be the scalars which is multiplied with the given set $$S=\{(1,2,1),(1,1,-1),(4,5,-2)\}$$

$\alpha(1,2,1) + \beta(1,1,-1) + \gamma(4,5,-2)= (0,0,0)$ but the equation becomes inconsistent. Even I tried to get the answer in calculator but it shows 'math error'. I began checking all the options but every time I check for the value of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ it shows 'math error'.
Please tell me where did I go wrong because I don't think that none of the options shouldn't be in the span $[S]$ and please use Gauss-elimination method to try this problem. I believe that my method is wrong because when I tried the next question with polynomials, it gave me the same inconsistent result.

Comment: There's an **obvious** solution to $$\alpha(1,2,1) + \beta(1,1,-1) + \gamma(4,5,-2)= (0,0,0)$$ It's $$(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = (0,0,0)$$ of course!  No calculator or math programs necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the equation is not solvable, it means that your vector $\notin [S]$.
As for the $(0, 0, 0)$ example, just put $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$, it is trivial example.

Answer (score 0):

The Gauss elimination method is to transform the generating vectors to get a simpler form. So calling $a=(1,2,1),b=(1,1,-1),c=(4,5,-2)$, we subtract $a$ from $b$ and $4a$ from $c$ to get: $(0,-1,-2)$ and $(0,-3,-6)$. We now subtract three times $(0,-1,-2)$ from $(0,-3,-6)$ to get $(0,0,0)$. This is now in the Gaussian form. We obviously drop $(0,0,0)$ because it cannot contribute anything. So we take our new vectors as $a=(1,2,1)$ and $d=(0,-1,-2)$.

I suspect you got into difficulties partly because you failed to drop one of the vectors.

It is not strictly part of the Gauss method, but it is convenient to replace $a$ by $e=a+2d=(1,0,-3)$.

So the general element of the span is $\lambda e+\mu d=(\lambda,\mu,-3\lambda+2\mu)$. In other words $(r,s,t)$ is in the span iff $t=2s-3r$.

So we see that 1,3,4 are in the span, but 2,5,6 are not.

If you stuck strictly to the Gauss approach you would reason as follows:

1. $(0,0,0)=0\cdot a$;
2. To get $\lambda a+\mu d=(1,1,0)$ we must have $\lambda=1$ (to get the 1st coordinate correct), then $2-\mu=1$ so $\mu=1$ to get the 2nd coordinate correct. But then the 3rd coordinate is -1. So $(1,1,0)$ is not in the span.
3. Similarly, we need $\lambda=2,\mu=5$ which works: $2(1,2,1)+5(0,-1,-2)=(2,-1,-8)$.
4. We need $\lambda=-\frac{1}{3},\mu=-\frac{1}{3}$ which works: $-\frac{1}{3}(1,2,1)-\frac{1}{3} (0,-1,-2)=(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$.
5. We need $\lambda=1,\mu=2$, which gives 3rd coordinate -3. So $(1,0,1)$ is not in the span.
6. We need $\lambda=1,\mu=5$, which gives 3rd coordinate -9. So $(1,-3,5)$ is not in the span.

Comment: I have never been taught this way using $\lambda$ $\mu$. So could you explain me how $\lambda$.a+$\mu$.b came??

Comment: Also why we took only a and d??

Comment: Well if you prefer using matrices you can just express it in matrix form.

Comment: You only need two vectors because the original set was not linearly independent.

Comment: Actually sir hasn't taught us the matrix method yet. So he has strictly told us to use elimination method. So i wanted to solve that way